# Render elements vertically and float to left when it's "overflowing" container

Tags: html, css

I have a design as in [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6wpcNDR2p_hdHJmNmU3bll0OUU/view?usp=sharing) picture

[image: design]

Basiclly, I have a container with fixed height(fx, 300px).
I need to render the list vertically with width: 33%, and if the list is too long, over-flowing list should float to the left.

```css
.container {
  width: 940px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #dedede;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.item {
  width: 31.2%;
  background-color: #B49AD9;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.item > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.item ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.alpha {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h2>The C container should float to left and place next to A</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="alpha">A</div>
    <div class="words">
      <ul>
        <li>Alll</li>
        <li>Aoooo</li>
        <li>Auuuuu</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="alpha">B</div>
    <div class="words">
      <ul>
        <li>Blll</li>
        <li>Boooo</li>
        <li>Buuu</li>
        <li>Baaaaa</li>
        <li>Boppoe</li>
        <li>Buuuuu</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="alpha">C</div>
    <div class="words">
      <ul>
        <li>Clll</li>
        <li>Coooo</li>
        <li>Cuuu</li>
        <li>Coppoe</li>
        <li>Cuuuuu</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The purple box with C should move beside A

How can I achieve this? Both css and js are welcome :)

PS: It needs to support at least IE9... ...

Comment: you can use CSS `column` structure

Comment: @Tushar - perhaps should've mentioned it's a CSS thing, and, more importantly, doesn't work on internet exploder 9 or earlier

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/

Comment: your main issues are: 
1) you have a fixed width of the of the containing div(so the big container is never getting smaller, so the smaller divs will never adjust)
2) you are not floating any of the smaller divs

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;          /* Magic begins*/
  flex-flow: column wrap; /* Multiline column layout */
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 940px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #dedede;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;          /* Magic begins*/
  flex-flow: column wrap; /* Multiline column layout */
}
.item {
  width: 31.2%;
  background-color: #B49AD9;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.item > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.item ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.alpha {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h2>The C container should float to left and place next to A</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="alpha">A</div>
    <div class="words">
      <ul>
        <li>Alll</li>
        <li>Aoooo</li>
        <li>Auuuuu</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="alpha">B</div>
    <div class="words">
      <ul>
        <li>Blll</li>
        <li>Boooo</li>
        <li>Buuu</li>
        <li>Baaaaa</li>
        <li>Boppoe</li>
        <li>Buuuuu</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="alpha">C</div>
    <div class="words">
      <ul>
        <li>Clll</li>
        <li>Coooo</li>
        <li>Cuuu</li>
        <li>Coppoe</li>
        <li>Cuuuuu</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oriol, but it has to support at least IE9.